# python: pickle.load() raising EOFError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a pickle file using .txt format. I want to load this pickle file with python 2.7. The size is 438.5 MB. This is how I load data :

```
def readpickle(path="C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/"):
with open(path+"filenamereal2.txt","rb") as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

return model
```

And I get this error

```
    itemmodelreal=readpickle(path="C:/Users/Lab Komputasi/Documents/estu/") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-33-265e46f74915>", line 1, in <module>
    itemmodelreal=readpickle(path="C:/Users/Lab Komputasi/Documents/estu/")

  File "<ipython-input-31-fbd3e8b9e043>", line 3, in readpickle
    model = pickle.load(f)

  File "C:\Users\Lab Komputasi\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()

  File "C:\Users\Lab Komputasi\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)

  File "C:\Users\Lab Komputasi\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 886, in load_eof
    raise EOFError

EOFError
```

this is the code that i use to write pickle :

```
 with open("filenamereal3.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(result, f)
f.close()
```

I have used read binary ('rb') to load and write binary ('wb') to write, but it's still have that error.
Do you have any idea why it's still error? how can i solve this error?

Thank you for your help....

Comment: We can't see which file you're unpickling, are you sure it's the correct one? And are you really opening it in `rb` mode? Would be nice if we could see the code you use for unpickling.

Comment: @Rawing sorry, i have edited it now

Comment: You're dumping to `filenamereal3` but loading `filenamereal2`?

Comment: Though might not be your case, _EOFError_ can also occur when you are trying to read an empty file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To load data, wouldn't you want to be reading data ("rb") instead of writing data ("wb")?

Loading data should look like this:

```
 with open("C:/Users/Lab Komputasi/Documents/estu/filenamereal1.txt", "rb") as f:
     data = pickle.load(f)
```

Also, using f.close() is unnecessary because you are using a with/as clause.

Comment: thx for your advice but i have used that code without f.close() but it was an error about `valueerror i/o operation on closed file` so I was suggested to use it. But after the eror was solved. The code has an `EOFError`

Comment: @estu Then I don't know how to solve the problem! Your code looks perfectly fine. Make sure your file is not damaged/corrupt. Also, you can read up on the documentation on End-of-File error, and make sure whatever you are pickling is pickle-able.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same error while loading a big file dumped in highest protocol.

This seems to be a bug of the pickle library. I solved it using cPickle instead.

```
import cPickle as pickle
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. It seems pickle has problems with large files, while cPickle does not.

Comment: Reader, this might be wrong for your case.  Consider that a large pickle file might be being written while you are trying to read it.  That was the problem in my case

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your pickle file is not empty, e.g. if you pickle an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was reading class objects from a .txt file. This seemed to work for me:

```
try: 
    <my code>
except EOFError:
     break
```